# String to JSON Object Convert iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

From the Server, I am receiving the below string as (AnyHashable : String)

```
{Type:1, OrderId:174}
```

I know it is not a valid Json String, but I have to deal with **Type** and **OrderId** separately

I am converting a string to JSONObject but as my string is invalid, therefore below code not converting it.

```
if let tag = notification.request.content.userInfo["tag"]{
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tag, options: []) {
            // here `json` is your JSON data
            print(json)
        }
    }
```

Anyone can suggest what should I do to get Type and OrderId value so I can handle the response? Or I have to convert string to json and then convert to JSONObject?

Comment: The server response is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes I know, thats y I have to convert it

Comment: is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the string is not valid JSON you have to convert it manually.

The code

- Removes the leading and trailing braces.
- Splits the string by `", "`.
- Converts each item to `[String:Int]`.

It assumes that all keys are `String` and all values are `Int`

```
let string = "{Type:1, OrderId:174}"
let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "{}"))
let components = trimmedString.components(separatedBy: ", ")
var result = [String:Int]()
_ = components.map { item in
    let keyValue = item.components(separatedBy: ":")
    result[keyValue[0]] = Int(keyValue[1])
}
```

Console:

```
["Type": 1, "OrderId": 174]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, let me try it, thanks for your response @vadian

Comment: Thanks, man, I changed the code little bit for my requirements. Now the result can be ended/decoded in JSON.